# Skip non capturing groups in regex

Tags: regex

I wrote a regex to capture certain fields in the windows event logs, below is the regex:

```
(?:Subject\:)(?<Subject>.+)$[\n](?:Created)
```

Below are the sample windows event logs which match the Regex.

```
Log: ABC
Source: DocumentService
Level: Error
Subject: 

ABC.BizService.DocumentVendors.DocumentVendorException: No Instances

Created On (UTC): 7/6/2017 8:57:04 PM
Created On (Local Machine): 7/6/2017 4:57:04 PM

System Information
Machine: Server1
Operating System: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
Process ID: 1360
Process Name: abc.Server.Document
System Name: PROD
Domain: Dom1
User: DOM1\66

Message ID: 0
Transaction Context: 0
Exception Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Submitted Message: 

Error building document '638. No Instances'
```

When i use the output of the Regex i get the below output:

```
ABC.BizService.DocumentVendors.DocumentVendorException: No Instances

Created On (UTC): 7/6/2017 8:57:04 PM
```

In the final output i even want to exclude this `Created On` field and everything after that. If you notice i just want to capture what is being written in the `Subject` Field. Looks like in my Regex i am even taking care of non capturing group. But they are still appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.+` is greedy, the capture group is matching everything up to the *second* `Created` line, so the first `Created` line is being included in the match.

Use a non-greedy quantifier `.+?` to get the shortest match rather than the longest one.

```
(?:Subject\:)(?<Subject>.+?)$[\n](?:Created)
```